# Subversion - What do I need to back up?

Tags: svn, repository, backup

I have a question about Subversion. I have always been an end user so my knowledge of how it actually works is, well, let’s just say very limited (so please forgive if this is a stupid question).

I have WAMP installed and do my initial development and testing using it. Therefore `C:\wamp\www\` contains the code for what I am working on at the time and I test using `http://localhost/template/`

Then I decided to install Subversion using the instructions I had found at http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/setting-up-subversion-on-windows.html. I installed to `c:\svn` and created `c:\svn\repository` and added my project with the following command:

```
svn mkdir svn://localhost/template
```

I now checkout to `C:\wamp\www\` which means that I now have a directory structure that looks like this:

`C:\wamp\www\template` which contains folders called branches, tags, trunk and website. The website folder contains the code for the project and I test using `http://localhost/template/website`

**Now to my question**

What is the physical location that `svn://localhost/template` saves to? So when I make changes in my working copy `C:\wamp\www\template` and commit them, *where does it save to?
Does it contain a copy of the original files?*

Why I ask: I am trying to figure out **what/how to back up my repository**. In my mind I think I should only have to backup **c:\svn\repository** but when I look in there, I don’t see any of my code.

Thank you for your help, it is very much appreciated.
Angie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get an idea :

**Where subversion keep your souce code?**

Check the question : [Using Subversion, where is “actual” source code stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763167/using-subversion-where-is-actual-source-code-stored)

**What is the best way to backup subversion repositories?**

Check the question:  [what is the best way to backup subversion repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055/what-is-the-best-way-to-backup-subversion-repositories)

Answer (score 1):

The c:\svn\repository folder is where your checkins are saved.  If you look under there, you should see \db\revs\ - this folder contains the info about the checkin (though not in an easy-to-read format.)

You should backup c:\svn\repository.

Comment: Does it also contain a copy of the original files (just not in the original format)? So if I back up c:\svn\repository and my hard drive crashes and I reinstall to a new hard drive and put down c:\svn\repository from back up EVERYTHING will be there?

Comment: @Angie: Yes, that's the idea of a backup, isn't it? :-)

Comment: Yes, everything you checked in will be there

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you only have to backup C:\svn\repository. You don't see your code as it is not stored in a directory tree. It is stored in the files in the folder C:\svn\repository\db\revs.

In your working copy you have the hidden .svn folders in every folder of your directory structure. Inside these folders is the version of your code at the moment you made your last SVN Update or SVN Commit.